# VB script to automate importing sharepoint list data to excel

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript, sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel

I need to automate pulling data from SharePoint list data to excel through writing a VB Script (not VBA).

How can I import data directly from a SharePoint List into Excel using VB script?

Currently, I am manually exporting to an Excel file. I would like to eliminate that manual step.

I've searched online but am not coming up with any good results. Any ideas where I can start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Export the spreadsheet from SharePoint
2. Go to the "Data" tab in the spreadsheet and click "Connections"

[image: Connections button]

3. There should be one connection. Select it and click "Properties"
4. Tick the "enable background refresh"

[image: Connection properties window]

5. The "Refresh All" button in the data tab will now update the spreadsheet without having to export it from sharepoint. Create a script to automate this.